# How much power can a 10W solar panel produce under ideal but achievable conditions?

Tags: solar-cell

How much power can a 10W solar panel produce?
Can it go beyond 10W?

Comment: No load means no current. And that means no power.

Comment: Zero load resistance means no _voltage_ and therefore no power. Infinite load resistance means no current and therefore no power.

Comment: It can still absorb the radiation and give some heat. My guess = the solar constant multiplied by the sunny side surface area. I'm afraid most of it evaporates to air. If the electric output ability is 10W the heat output can be much bigger.

Comment: I edited the heading slightly to forestall pedantic comments. ||

Comment: THIS QUESTION IS A REASONABLE ONE. I've edited it slightly to make the question being asked more closely match what the op OBVIOUSLY intended. Pedantic responses to slightly flawed wording do nobody much good.

Answer (score 3):

Summary:

You can get MORE than 10W from a 10W rated PV panel in some situations.   .
In a few locations under ideal conditions you may get as much as ~= 14W from a 10W panel.

---

Detail:

Panels are (almost always) rated under standard operationg conditions of

- 1000 W/m^2 "insolation" (solar energy)
- 25 degrees C panel temperature and
- No wind
- A solar spectrum achieved from standard atmospheric path termed AM1.5 (air mass 1.5)
  AM1.5 approximates an average path through the atmosphere across a typical day.

Temperatures above 25 C lead to lower maximum power output.

Maximum insolation is typically achieved at noon on a cloudless day with the panel pointing at the sun.
1 kW/m^2 is what is typically achieved.
SOME locations on earth can achieve insolations of up to about 1400 W/m^2.

Where are you located.
Gaisma is an excellent site for establishing insolation levels by month and many other location related factors. [Here](https://www.gaisma.com/en/location/kabul.html) is the Gaisma page for Kabil in Afghanistan - one of the sunniest places on earth.
Locations around the world are available on Gaisma.
[Here](https://www.gaisma.com/en/location/new-york-ny.html) is data for NY NY USA (about 70% of Kabul figures).
And [Glasgow, UK](https://www.gaisma.com/en/location/glasgow.html) :-(

Many related links [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=standard+solar+panel+operating+conditions&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=standard+solar+panel+operating+conditions&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.14470j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

The MPT condition is nominally around Vmpt= 80 ~82 % of Voc at max solarity and 90% of Isc

The PV source equivalent incremental impedance is approximated by this ratio

\$Voc/Isc= Rmpt= 22V/0.9A=24.4 Ohms\$
, which is the ideal load at max solarity and max power out.

Rmpt then rises with lower power input.

This requires voltage tracking in a converter to match impedances with a switched inductor+cap. or battery charger or regulator.

\$Pmax=0.8Voc*I=15.8W\$ minus diode losses when used for protection.

However at Voc, Isc, there is no power out, because the other term is 0 in P= V*I.

The MPT condition is nominally around Vmpt= 80 ~82 % of Voc at max solarity.

But recomputing PV source impedance is 0.82/0.9==22/0.9 * 0.82/0.9 = 22 Ohms. This should occur at 18V = 0.82 * 22V with about 14W.

Good luck , report back your test results in Q.

**Test method Validation**

Using a power resistor of R=24 Ohms >=10W immersed in water for cooling, report Isc, Voc, Vmpt, Impt and compute power.

Alternatively use a power NPN transistor rated for > 14W also immersed in water, adjust bias for a common emitter to sink Impt (Ib=Ic/hFE) with Ib = Vout/R or a Darlington allowing less Pd in higher R pot, adjust for VI=Pmpt. Then report all measured and computed results for Rmpt, Pmpt in question.

Comment: Under a hot sunny weather, can it go beyond  10W?

Comment: If it's rated at 10W on the sunniest day, no.

Comment: @user_1818839 i see, thanks

Comment: @user_1818839 Yes, it can. See my answer.

Comment: Tony: Interest only: Imp/Isc  varies with cell efficiency and is higher at high Z. || Fill factor (misleading term) = Imp.Vmp/Isc.Voc and is a useful guide to what can be expected.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Per your answer, not in Glasgow where I am! (but +1)

Comment: @user_1818839  [Gaisma - Glasgow](https://www.gaisma.com/en/location/glasgow.html) as per my answer - I must have known :-). 4.55 kWh/m^2 in June average.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon so you agree with my calculations of 14W max?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  I got ~= the same wattage as you but it seems for different reasons. Mine was from Imp x Vmp x Max_likely_Insolation/(1 kW/m^2). In somewhere like Kabul the max insolation can be well above the 1 kW/m^2 std value

Comment: Mine were simply from common characteristics and actual readings vs insolation variances.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the heading, the answer is "none".  If there is no load, the solar panel will produce no power at all.

To answer the question in the body, then a 10W panel will be designed to produce 10W under ideal sunny conditions.  If you can achieve something even sunnier than that, you may get more than 10W out of it.  Perhaps arrange a series of reflectors that track the sun, reflecting more light onto the panel.  Provided the panel doesn't melt from all the heat, it should produce more than 10W.

Comment: See my answer. The conditions used are standard ones but NOT ideal ones. Substantially more output is possible in some locations - eg Kabul.